# va_args breaks wide string functions (swprintf) in XCode

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions, widestring

In Xcode only (visual studio is fine), I am seeing swprintf break if you attempt to put it in a wrapper function using va_args.

Simplified example:

```
void test( wchar_t *a_buffer, int a_buffer_size, const wchar_t* a_format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, a_format);
    ::swprintf(a_buffer, a_buffer_size, a_format, args );
    va_end(args);
}

double value = 1.0;
wchar_t text[32];
::swprintf( text, 32, L"%f", value ); // this works (text=L"1.0000")

test(text, 32, L"%f", 30.0); // this does not work (text=L"0.0000")
```

Any help appreciated, it's quite a stumper. I'm assuming the issue is with some quirk of XCode.

I have already messed with Locale Settings and file properties as suggested in this question: [swprintf fails with unicode characters in xcode, but works in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885094/swprintf-fails-with-unicode-characters-in-xcode-but-works-in-visual-studio) but it has not yielded any change, it looks like a separate issue.

Thanks.

Comment: `swprintf()` does _not_ take a varargs argument. You mean to be using `vswprintf()`.

Comment: vswprintf() is indeed what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a va_list object, then use

```
int vswprintf(
    const wchar_t* buffer,
    size_t bufsz,
    const wchar_t* format, 
    va_list vlist );
```

The trailing ... just means its argument could vary in length, but it doesn't mean that you could pass a va_list object directly.

Comment: That was indeed my problem, I thought va_list could be passed to ... functions. Using vswprintf inside the test() function solved it, thank you.